# Pass function to child in react: the react way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I am very new to React and I am still not entirely sure how to pass functions from parent to child with the caveat that the function should be used as a callback in one of the child's functions. (That's what makes this question different from other questions.)

The following code is a stripped down version of the actual code. It works, but I am not sure whether this is the 'react' way of doing this.

```
class Text extends Component {
  state = {
    a: [],
    b: []
  }

  updateShelves = (books) => {
    this.setState({
      'a': books.filter(book => book.letter === 'a'),
      'b': books.filter(book => book.letter === 'b')
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {
        Object.keys(this.state).map((letter, idx) => (
          {this.state[letter].map((book, idx) => (
            <Sentence key={'book-' + idx} book={book} onShelfChange={this.updateShelves}/>
          ))})
      }
    </div>
  )
  }
}

class Sentence extends Component {
  updateSentence = (newLetter, callback) => {
    TextAPI.update(this.props.book, newLetter).then(() => {
      // Parent function finally gets called here as a callback
      TextAPI.getAll().then(books => callback(books))
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {book, onShelfChange} = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={(event) => this.updateSentence(event.target.value, onShelfChange)} defaultValue={book.shelf}>
        // HTML option elements
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So now I pass down the parent's function as a property to the child, which in turn passes that property to its function as a callback. I am doubtful because it seems that this is a lot of 'passing functions as arguments' for such a simple thing. Is this the correct way to go about this use-case?

Comment: this.updateBook where is this function defined?

Comment: what is the use of TextAPI.update?

Comment: I suggest to read this article on `this` binding: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala Oops. Copy-paste error. The update is just something that updates that database. It reflects the changes in the parent's state, but saves it to a database.

Comment: did you log your code and check till where your call works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Sentence component, `onShelfChange` function will be available in all the methods, so no need of passing that function to `updateBook` method in arguments.

`updateBook` method has the access of class instance that means you can directly access that method.

Like this:

```
updateSentence = (newLetter) => {
    TextAPI.update(this.props.book, newLetter)
    .then(() => {
        TextAPI.getAll().then(books => this.props.onShelfChange(books))
    })
}
```

**Suggestions:**

**1-** You can avoid the creation of multiple function, by writing it like this:

```
<select onChange={this.updateSentence} ...

updateSentence = (event) => { 
   const newLetter = event.target.value;
   ....
}
```

**2-** Also you can use `Object.values` and write the loop like this:

```
{
    Object.values(this.state).map((letter, idx) => (
        letter.map((book, idx) => (
            <Sentence key={'book-' + idx} book={book} onShelfChange={this.updateShelves}/>
        ))
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call it in the following function call itself.

```
<select onChange={this.updateBook} defaultValue={book.shelf}>
// HTML option elements
</select>

const updateBook = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if(typeof this.props.onShelfChange !== 'undefined){
        // call the parent callback function passed as prop here.
        this.props.onShelfChange(params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed the function as prop, you can call the prop directly:

```js
updateSentence = (newLetter) => {
    TextAPI.update(this.props.book, newLetter).then(() => {
      TextAPI.getAll().then(books => this.props.onShelfChange(books)) // see here.
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {book} = this.props

    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={(event) => this.updateSentence(event.target.value)} defaultValue={book.shelf}>
        // HTML option elements
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
```